# PHP variable is not included when loading with javascript .how to include php inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

My js code re-loads the comments.php  in every 3 seconds .

I have included comments.php in index.php  and it does get all the variables from index.php but when js reloads comments.php   it does not get the variable and shows error .

First time it works cause it's included with php . After the re-load it's not included anymore .

How can i include comments.php  in index.php  inside js.

index.php

```html
<?php
if (isset($_GET['slug'])){

$page_id = $_GET['slug'];

}

?>



<div id="comments">
 <script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  setInterval(function(){
  
  $('#comments').load('comments.php')
  
  },3000);
  
  
  });
      
// when loading  comments.php with js  $page_id  is not gotten and showing error  
 


</script>
<?php include("comments.php") ; ?>

 // first time shows this and comments.php does get the   varible $page_id  
</div>
```

comments.php

```html
<?php 

$page_id = $_GET['slug'];

$get_com = " SELECT * FROM `comments` where post_id='$page_id' ORDER BY `comment_id` DESC ";

$run_com = mysql_query($get_com);


?>
```

Comment: Are you reloading the index.php?

Comment: reloading the comments.php  here  $('#comments').load('comments.php')

Comment: You need to pass the parameter: `$('#comments').load('comments.php?slug=5') `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `include("comments.php")` it inherits the variables from `index.php`. When you reload with `load('comments.php')` you are doing it via HTTP and there is no GET variable `slug` because you are not passing it:

```
$('#comments').load('comments.php?slug=<?=urlencode($page_id)?>')
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to simply echo the PHP variable to JavaScript:

```
var page_id = '<? echo $page_id ?>';
var get_com = '<? echo $get_com ?>';
var run_com = '<? echo $run_com ?>';
```

Assuming those variables are populated by the time the PHP is finished, JavaScript will be able to make use of them.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how is that?

Comment: $page_id is actually a copy of $_GET['slug'];
You should escape it when you output it to the user: var page_id = <? echo json_encode($page_id) ?>;